# Name of author who wrote books for pre-teens and teens about "classic" sci-fi and horror movies

Tags: books, young-adult, story-identification, kaiju

I had two books by this author back in the 1980s when I was a teenager. Both books were pretty thin paperbacks (no more than 100 or so pages). One book was about science fiction movies, mostly from the 1950s. I remember the cover of the book had one or two of the spaceships from the original "War of the Worlds," along with one of the aliens. I *think* that one of the big-brained aliens from "This Island Earth" was on the cover too.

The horror/monster movie book featured a lot of Ray Harryhausen movies, Japanese kaiju movies, and the omnipresent giant bug movies of the 1950s. This book featured Gorgo (England's answer to Godzilla) and Rodan on the cover.

I've been wracking my brain trying to remember the names of both books, along with the author's name. Like I said, he wrote both books. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hello. It is most definitely not Forrest J. Ackerman, but someone why more obscure. Thanks!

Comment: I feel like I owned at least a couple of books like this.  In elementary school, we had an annual book sale and each of us got X number of credits towards buying books, and you could bring money and buy as many as you chose.  I always bought the books about monster movies and the latest edition of The Guinness Book of World Records, for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I got this book too.

Answer (score 2):

Your description of the horror book reminds me of something that I had a long times ago (must have been mid 1970s). I'm pretty sure it was called "Monsters from the Movies".

Google turns up one book with this title (possibly aka "Movie Monsters") by Thomas G Aylesworth.

Not much official info ([amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055315091X) have some reviews)

I can't find an equivalent SF book by the same author however.

Comment: I saw this book too when I did a Google search. That's not the book, unfortunately, but it is along the same lines. The monster book I am thinking of has a dark blue cover, with an orange Gorgo, along with an orange Rodan in the background.

Comment: @JasonBodak I don't recognise the covers Google returns. IIRC my copy had The Creature from the Black Lagoon on the cover. Maybe there are many versions.

Comment: I think the book I'm thinking of had the Creature from the Black Lagoon, but I'm pretty none of the other Universal monsters were in it. The book primarily focused on Ray Harryhausen's movies (from "King Kong" to the Sinbad movies), 1950s giant bug movies ("Them!," "The Deadly Mantis," etc.) and Japanese kaiju movies (Godzilla, Rodan, etc.).